# How to redirect from your website (currently building) to an app installed in your phone (android os)

Tags: android, html, augmented-reality

I am currently building an e-commerce website, I want to implement the following functionality :
When I click an image/ a button on my website I want my website to open an app pre installed on my phone from play store or it could be better if I could prompt the user to download the app from play store if it is not there in the system and give the play store link to download the app.
The actual requirement is that I have a glb format file with me and I want to open that file with a preinstalled AR viewer app in my android phone how can I implement this in my website.
Is there any options to view a glb format file in AR using android phone

Answer (score 1):

that can be achieved with [App links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links) (it's like v2 of [Deep linking](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking), extending it). you can parametrize such link, which:

- will open app if installed with passing clicked URL (so you can download file/show site/whatever on app-side)
- if not installed link may redirect to your custom landing site or Play Store for downloading app. with second option when after installation user press "Open" button in Play Store app then your link will also be passed to freshly installed app and you can work with it like in first case when app already installed
- App links are detecting OS, so are universal for Android and iOS and can redirect to proper store or open a different site. also when link opened on e.g. desktop OS then fall-back site URL will be opened